Is there any way that i can implement to curve the moving line on edges ? Implementing in Flutter
My code as of now:
class RoundedRectanglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color strokeColorGradientStart;
  final Color strokeColorGradientEnd;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final double borderRadius;
  final Color fillColorGradientStart;
  final Color fillColorGradientEnd;
  final Animation<double> animation;

  RoundedRectanglePainter({
    required this.strokeColorGradientStart,
    required this.strokeColorGradientEnd,
    required this.strokeWidth,
    required this.borderRadius,
    required this.fillColorGradientStart,
    required this.fillColorGradientEnd,
    required this.animation,
  }) : super(repaint: animation);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final strokeGradient = LinearGradient(
      colors: [strokeColorGradientStart, strokeColorGradientEnd],
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
    );

    final fillGradient = LinearGradient(
      colors: [fillColorGradientStart, fillColorGradientEnd],
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
    );

    final strokePaint = Paint()
      ..shader = strokeGradient
          .createShader(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    final fillPaint = Paint()
      ..shader = fillGradient
          .createShader(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final outerRect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    final outerRRect =
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(outerRect, Radius.circular(borderRadius));
    canvas.drawRRect(outerRRect, strokePaint);

    final innerWidth = size.width - (strokeWidth * 2) - 10;
    final innerHeight = size.height - (strokeWidth * 2) - 10;
    final innerRect = Rect.fromLTWH((size.width - innerWidth) / 2,
        (size.height - innerHeight) / 2, innerWidth, innerHeight);
    final innerRRect =
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(innerRect, Radius.circular(borderRadius));

    canvas.drawRRect(innerRRect, fillPaint);

    Path outerPath = Path()..addRRect(outerRRect);
    PathMetrics pathMetrics = outerPath.computeMetrics();
    PathMetric pathMetric = pathMetrics.first;

    double currentLength = pathMetric.length * animation.value;
    Tangent? tangent = pathMetric.getTangentForOffset(currentLength);

    if (tangent != null) {
      final movingLinePaint = Paint()
        ..color = Colors.red
        ..strokeWidth = 10.0
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

      final lineStart = tangent.position;
      final lineDirection = tangent.vector;

      final lineEnd = lineStart +
          Offset(
            lineDirection.dx * 30,
            lineDirection.dy * 30,
          );

       canvas.drawLine(lineStart, lineEnd, movingLinePaint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}

i want that the line moving should follow the exact path as the outer rectangle is defined. i tried and tested different thing but not able to get the desired behaviour. how can i proceed further to achieve the desired functionality or behaviour or some relevant code snippet which can help me progress in the code.
in the image you can see when it reaches the curved path the line moving is not following the curveness, it simply takes a turn to right. this is the problem.


i simplified your RoundedRectanglePainter class, check my answer below

instead of pathMetric.getTangentForOffset use pathMetric.extractPath, notice that it has to be called twice when trying to get a sub-path at the end of the given path
the complete code (note: timeDilation = 5; is used just for testing, your are free to delete it):
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Foo()));

class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Durations.extralong4);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: RoundedRectanglePainter(
            strokeColors: [Colors.green.shade900, Colors.green.shade700, Colors.blue.shade900, Colors.grey],
            strokeWidth: 12,
            borderRadius: 32,
            fillColors: [Colors.pink.shade700, Colors.grey.shade600, Colors.indigo.shade900],
            padding: 6,
            animation: _controller,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => _controller.forward(from: 0), child: const Text('animate')),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class RoundedRectanglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double strokeWidth;
  final double borderRadius;
  final double padding;
  final Animation<double> animation;
  final Gradient strokeGradient;
  final Gradient fillGradient;

  RoundedRectanglePainter({
    required List<Color> strokeColors,
    required this.strokeWidth,
    required this.borderRadius,
    required List<Color> fillColors,
    this.padding = 10,
    required this.animation,
  }) :
    strokeGradient = LinearGradient(
      colors: strokeColors,
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
    ),
    fillGradient = LinearGradient(
      colors: fillColors,
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
    ),
    super(repaint: animation);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // slow motion - just for testing
    timeDilation = 5;

    // rects
    final outerRect = (Offset.zero & size).deflate(strokeWidth / 2);
    final innerRect = outerRect.deflate(padding + strokeWidth / 2);

    // paints
    final strokePaint = Paint()
      ..shader = strokeGradient.createShader(outerRect)
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    final fillPaint = Paint()
      ..shader = fillGradient.createShader(innerRect)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    final movingLinePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    // round rects
    final outerRRect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(outerRect, Radius.circular(borderRadius));
    final innerRRect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(innerRect, Radius.circular(borderRadius - padding - strokeWidth / 2));

    // moving sub-path
    final outerPath = Path()..addRRect(outerRRect);
    final pathMetric = outerPath.computeMetrics().first;
    final start = pathMetric.length * animation.value;
    final end = start + borderRadius * pi * 0.5;
    final path = pathMetric.extractPath(start, end);
    if (end > pathMetric.length) {
      path.addPath(pathMetric.extractPath(0, end - pathMetric.length), Offset.zero);
    }

    // draw everything
    canvas
      ..drawRRect(outerRRect, strokePaint)
      ..drawRRect(innerRRect, fillPaint)
      ..drawPath(path, movingLinePaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}

